# Operating System Not Found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

Installed Elementary via the live usb to D drive. C Drive is windows ssd. In boot order have changed so the D drive is higher in the boot order than C. When order is reversed, the C drive works as usual. When the D drive is first I get a 'no operating system found' message.

I've checked the checksum of the download and installed the usb as per the guide. Am installing whilst connected to a wired internet connection.

What setting do I need to change to get this to work? Have heard suggestion that it is a grub error, how then to install grub when I cannot access the operating system?

Regards

Comment: Which device did you select to install grub

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Boot into the live usb and open terminal
- Open terminal and write this:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> ```

- On the window, click on 'Recommended repair' and follow the instructions

That should work. If not, try to reinstall elementary OS by the default configuration, choosing the 'install alongside windows' option.

Answer (score 1):

This always works for me:

1. download & create liveimage of supergrub iso.
2. boot super grub.
3. locate bootable OS on the pc. ( if more than one OS on the PC)
4. boot you preferred OS.
5. Login & go terminal as root.
6. usually most people prefer grub on "/dev/sda" but that's no always the case. So select the drive you prefer to install grub on.
7. run "grub-install /dev/sd?" change the "?" to the letter of the drive you wish to install grub on.
8. then run "update-grub" that should do it.

you could also run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Note:
A. I always suggest installing "grub-customizer", this is a great graphical app to manage your grub. ie. update,add, change the OS boot order , backup & save grub. Even move to a different drive.
B. Supergrub disk or "RESCATUX" are incredible tools to carry around with you.