# After instalation, boot error message: can not find any operational system

Tags: release-loki, boot, uefi

After a clean installation of Elementary Loki, there is an error message during the booting that does not allow me run Elementary. "Cannot find any operational system". As I am not an expert, the only solution I found was change Legacy instead of UEFI inside the BIOS, and wallah! is working now.

However, although is working now I suppose something is wrong with my GRUB and I should fix it to be able to boot Elementary with UEFI. I would really appreciate any orientation about how to fix it.

This question it was already posted here [Force UEFI installation?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7856/force-uefi-installation) but unfortunately did not find a real solution.

*Some additional information: Elementary is the only OS I'm running in my laptop right now. However, previously the laptop was using Windows 10 that came in for default. My laptop is a Sony Vaio, S series.

Comment: There is already a similar question around. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5345/operating-system-not-found . I haven't flagged your question as duplicated because I like your exposition. If you read it and it's helpful please let me know so I can report it as duplicated.

Comment: Before doing anything on that link check if you are using a GPT partition table. Because if you aren't, you'll have to install everything again. 
`sudo parted -l | grep Partition`

Comment: Hmm i think that is not the problem with our OS i think its problem with your method . Can u please explain the method that you used for clean boot please explain your boot procedure . We can help you out soon please reply soon waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using Elementary OS in UEFI, and don't plan on using legacy mode for anything, it may be useful to turn off Legacy Option ROM in your BIOS. Ensuring that the boot mode is UEFI, and you boot into the OS in UEFI mode. Disabling Secure Boot beforehand also eliminates some risk, as you'll need to disable it anyway. You may want to delete any existing UEFI operating systems from the UEFI directory. Once booted into the installer, you should be free and clear. I'd you intend to manually configure your partitions, ensure the partition table is GPT, and you create a ~512MB EFI system partition. Automatic partitioning should take care of this though.

Answer (score 0):

There is workaround process that i found when i try to install eOS loki/Ubuntu 16.04 using UEFI mode(want to remove windows 10)

- First, install eOS (force UEFI) normally. Reboot, this time you will face there is no operating system.
- Enter the installation process and install the eOS again. This time the installation will proceed with UEFI mode. You may recreate all of your partition again with EFI boot partition (recommend - create all partition again).
- After finish, reboot to the system. Check if your installation is in UEFI mode using this command: `sudo efibootmgr`

Sorry for my bad English.